# Stop visual studio orderedtest execution if a particular test fails

Tags: vs-unit-testing-framework

My requirement is that a visual studio orderedtest execution should get stopped if a particular test fails. There is a setting "Continue After failure but setting it to false, will stop the orderedtest even if any other test fails.

My orderedtest should stop only if a particular test fails.

How do I achieve this?

Regards,

kvk938

Comment: Can anyone answer my query?